# How to assign and update the manager field based on the employee seup

Tags: apex

Below is the trigger to update the manager field from sobject employee_c and I am have a manager for this employee but I am getting list has no rows and stopping the application to proceed.

```
//Trigger to update the Managaer field based on the employee selected.
trigger Updatemanager on Leave_application__c(after insert) {
    for(Leave_application__c a: trigger.new){
        string EmployeeName= a.Employee_name__c;
        //Employee__c b = [SELECT Manager__c FROM Employee__c where Name=:name1];
        String name = [SELECT Manager__c FROM Employee__c where Name=:EmployeeName].Manager__c;

        //List<Employee__c> sobjs = database.query('Select Manager__c From Employee__c where Name in :EmployeeName');
        //list manager= new List([Select Manager__c from Employee__c where Name in :EmployeeName]);
        //list<string> manager= (string) [SELECT Manager__c FROM Employee__c where Name=:name1].Manager__c ;
        a.Manager__c= name ;
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line you are getting error ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to bulkify your code, and use the standard aggregate-query-update pattern:

```
trigger UpdateManager on Leave_Application__c (before insert, before update) {
  // Aggregate names together
  Map<String, String> managers = new Map<String, String>();
  for(Leave_Application__c la: Trigger.new) {
    managers.put(la.Employee_Name__c, null);
  }
  // Query for related data
  for(Employee__c emp: [SELECT Name, Manager__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Name = :managers.keySet()]) {
    managers.put(emp.Name, emp.Manager__c);
  }
  // Update records with data
  for(Leave_Application__c la: Trigger.new) {
    la.Manager__c = managers.get(la.Name);
  }
}
```

Note also that want to use *before* trigger events when updating a record already in the trigger, and *after* trigger events only when you want to update a *related* record.

Comment: Still then manager value was not able to extract based on the employee name passed

Comment: @user39579 Depending on the data type, you might simply be confusing normal strings with Id values.